# store DStream, check point, persist?

Tags: java, apache-kafka, spark-streaming

i'am new in spark streaming programing.
how can I display the result and store it and then the new result depends on the new DStream  and this old result.
spark version =1.6.0 kafka version 2.10 and java

please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use persist() method for saving intermediate results in memory or on disk depending upon the data volume.This can be accessed in the next dstream processing.
Checkpoint is for restarting the job from point of failure in case the streaming job restarts.Spark default checkpoint keeps track of the last successfully read kafka message and save the offset.But it does have a bug until 2.2 version of spark that it will reprocess the last successful dstream batch again on restart.Refer spark documentation below.
https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.6.0/streaming-programming-guide.html#caching--persistence